# Blazor(server-side) with IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to get an IdentityServer4 (with local API) working with a Blazor (server-side) front end.

I have been able to create the IdentityServer backend. The login functions work and it authenticates against an ASP.NET Identity setup on the backend. Once authenticated I can (using Postman) take the Bearer token and call the API to get successful results.

I want to know if anyone has figured out how to:

1. Auto redirect the Blazor (server-side) when going to a page that
   requires authorization
2. Once the user successfully logs into the
   IdentityServer, how do I pass that information into the context.User
   of the Blazor application. If this is even possible, I might have
   terminology wrong here.

I am hoping that the decision in the end isn't to just use the odic-client.js to make these calls. Even if that is the result would it be possible to take that information back from IdentityServer and shove that into the context.User?

UPDATE:

I have been able to tie the Blazor website to go directly to the IdentityServer (not an auto-direct wanted in #1) to test out the functionality.

The returnUrl is redirecting from the IdentityServer (upon successful signin). This also looks like it is writing the AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie to the Blazor website cookies.

Is there a way to get that information from the cookie (if it contains the user and bearer tokens)?

UPDATE:

I have found that it looks like the Blazor code might be trying to read the cookie but I don't know how to verify. I am getting this in the output:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedUserName_0='?' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id], [u].[AccessFailedCount], [u].[ConcurrencyStamp], [u].[Email], [u].[EmailConfirmed], [u].[LockoutEnabled], [u].[LockoutEnd], [u].[NormalizedEmail], [u].[NormalizedUserName], [u].[PasswordHash], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [u].[SecurityStamp], [u].[TwoFactorEnabled], [u].[UserName]
FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u]
WHERE [u].[NormalizedUserName] = @__normalizedUserName_0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (BQM.API), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult in 651.558ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectResultExecutor:Information: Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to https://localhost:44370/.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (BQM.API) in 777.6252ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed endpoint 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (BQM.API)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 890.8492ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44370/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/_Host'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {page = "/_Host", area = ""}. Executing page /_Host
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed page /_Host in 16.8805ms
```

Comment: This has been resolved with the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172840/how-do-you-create-a-api-identityserver-blazorserver-side-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this can help you.

I need the token, because I want to call a API protected by this token. You must Add thing to the Startup.cs and to retrieve it later you can look at the class below Startup.cs

Here is what needed in Startup.cs (the importen part is HttpContextAccessor).

You need the following using i Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

And then (still in Startup.cs):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = 
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
            options.ClientId = "AuthCodeClient";
            options.ClientSecret = "verrystrongpwd";
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("user.management.api");
            options.Scope.Add("identity-provider.Api");
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        // HttpContextAccessor
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();

........ maybe more code....
```

Her is the class where I retrieve info from HttpContext, as access_token

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Management.Ui.Services
{
  public class TokenContainer
  {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TokenContainer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected async Task AddRequestHeaders(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you add the HttpContextAccessor service twice?  

`services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();`